# how to get maven properties env value from controller?

Tags: spring, jsp, controller, environment-variables, maven-profiles

I  have maven build pom.xml configuration

```
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <properties>
            <env>local</env>

        </properties>

    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <env>dev</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <env>prod</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and build option as follow

```
<build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <directory>${basedir}/target</directory>
        <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources-${env}</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

is it possible to bring the env value on any controller? 
I want to put the env value and do the branch operation

Answer (score 0):

Probably the Short answer to your question is "No", but
I'll try to provide an overall answer here to clarify a couple of things

You should differentiate between maven which is a purely build tool and your application runtime.

Usually, it goes like this:

**Build Phase**

You call maven to build you artifact(s). It can be WAR, JAR, EAR file or anything else.
As a build tool maven is responsible for compiling your source code, testing it if you have tests to run, packaging the compiled classes (hence the jar/war/etc. artifact), and that's it.

**Runtime Phase**

After that, you run an application on server. Here the responsibility of spring / jsp starts, but in a nutshell this phase is a runtime phase, and by the time it happens you even don't know that the application was built and packaged by maven - it doesn't matter already. You have artifact - you run it

Now its clear that maven profile that defines some properties is something the is "relevant" during the build time and does not propagate to the runtime, because they won't exist there in general case.

Now you can trigger locally the startup of the application from maven (stuff like `mvn java:exec` if you use it) and in this case, you can probably fiddle with command line parameters, but again it's only for local development purposes, nothing to do with application life.

Technically speaking, if you absolutely need it, you can find a way to do this:

You can also create a way more complicated build that will read these properties in maven (some sort of maven plugin) and will generate a source file with these properties and their values, and if this happens before things get packaged (again by maven) the file will be "baked into your artifact" together with the rest of your code. So that it will be accessible at runtime because spring could read this property file.

The real question you should ask yourself is it a right thing to do? Usually, the answer is "no" here :)